# Functional tests and DB

Tags: database, testing, functional-testing

So question is - is it a good practice to ask DB for quantity of records in table to make test passed or even create some records right from functional test?

Comment: What do you suspect to be an answer here? Yes or no? To seriously answer your question it needs to be a bit more precise.

Comment: Well, for example, I have a group of functional tests for my API - list all users, get user, create user, delete user. And I have some test table with user entities. If I use static value with number of user entities, that I expect  to receive in test "get a list of all users", it will not pass in situation, when I run group of tests and test with user deletion goes first.
I hope this is more clear.

Comment: In case you are deleting a user group for testing purposes, you should arrange your tests in such a way that adding the user goes after deletion and then get all user test. You can also have multiple test user groups.